# Auto Update Android App is Incompatible with Old Version

Tags: android

I develop an App that has an auto update function. I cloned my project to my friend's laptop and gave away APK to several people. After sometime i made some update says it is incompatible with old version. So i wonder,

- Is it because the APKs were develop from different computer?
- Does it matter about having different versions of android studio?
- Is there a work around to give less hassle to the user? Because in
  this case, they have to uninstall the old version and install the new
  one.

Thank you

Comment: how do you create your apk?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira im using build apk from android studio, then get the apk in project's folder

Comment: you must use `Generate Signed APK` instead of build apk

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira if i produce signed apk, conflict wouldnt matter anymore no matter which device i use? Because during presentation i used laptop and sometimes do a quick change. Thank you for your response

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira i think signed apk requires app registration in playstore, i have no intention  of doing so because the app is only for specific persons. What should i do?

Comment: no.it doesnt need registration in playstore. check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

You Should See which Android Version Your Friends Phone Supports And What minimum Android Compatibility you have chosen while creating your Android Project.